# how to build odoo-12.0 for windows as an executable software?

Tags: python, odoo-12

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byBhY.png)I want to use odoo-12.0 locally, but I don’t want to install the python environment, so I want to package odoo-12.0 into an exe executable file. When I use pyintaller to package it into an exe, and copy odoo, addons, myaddons, odoo.conf Go to the current directory of the executable file, and modify the addons_path path in the configuration file to the absolute path of odoo, addons, myaddons in the exe directory, compile all py files in the current directory of the exe into pyc files, and change the name to Under the corresponding directory, delete py. After clicking, there is a problem with the exe. After double-clicking the exe file, an error occurs and the versions cannot be found. What caused this?

Comment: Please always include your stacktrace formatted as code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Hi xhaihui, welcome to SO.  please make some effort to format your question as well the steps you took to make it work. Remember you will get better responses if you make it easy to other users to respond to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pyinstaller --onefile`, it generates one .exe file including everything.